# Motivation of separated scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

A scheme is called separated if it is separated over $\mathbb{Z}$. Is there a specific reason to define like this, i.e. separated over $\mathbb{Z}$? I know Spec$\mathbb{Z}$ is a final object. But are there any other reasons or motivations?

Comment: The general idea is that schemes aren't separated, _morphisms_ of schemes are separated. So if you want to refer to a scheme as separated without reference to a morphism, then you should be assumed to be talking about the canonical morphism to the final object, $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$. This all goes back to Grothendieck preferring to do everything in the relative situation.

Comment: @KReiser what do you mean by schemes aren't separated at beginning? Do you mean Hausdorff? I mean you referred separated schemes before you motivate the definition of separated scheme, which is like a loop and confused me

Comment: I mean that you don't want to apply the property of "being separated" to the object "a scheme" - you want to apply the property of "being separated" to a morphism of schemes. Put differently, the description "separated" is an adjective, and the best noun for it to modify is "morphism of schemes", not "schemes".

Comment: @KReiser but why you don't want to apply the property to schemes?

Comment: Because Grothendieck (and lots of 20th century math) taught us that there's a lot to gain from looking at morphisms instead of objects. See [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck%27s_relative_point_of_view) and [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120147/why-do-we-look-at-morphisms) for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice fact which might be convincing:

> If a scheme $X$ is separated over $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$ then for every scheme $Y$ and every morphism $f:X\to Y$, the morphism $f$ is separated.

Here's one way to prove this: there is a general fact that if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are morphisms of schemes, and $P$ is a property of morphisms preserved under composition and base change, then under the hypothesis that $g\circ f$ has property $P$ and the diagonal of $g$ has property $P$, we can conclude $f$ has property $P$. In our case, we can take $P$ to be the property of separatedness, and then for $Z=\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$, $g\circ f$ must be the unique morphism $X\to\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$ (which is separated by assumption), and the diagonal of $g$ is separated because it is a locally closed immersion (this is true of the diagonal of any morphism), so we conclude $f$ is separated.

Answer (score 0):

One motivation can be given from topology: A space $X$ is called hausdorff, if for every pair of points $x \neq y$, there are open sets $x \in U$ and $y \in V$ such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Then it is a good exercise to show that $X$ is hausdorff if and only if the diagonal map $\Delta: X  \to X \times X$ is closed.

Actually, the analogy goes a bit further: A classical example of a non-hausdorff space is the real line with double $0$, that is obtained by gluing two copies of $\mathbb{R}$ along the set $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. The algebro-geometric analogue is the variety obtained by gluing two copies of $\mathbb{A}^n$ along $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{0\}$.